# Jquery live preview with javascript effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a page where you can write a sentence, and it display well designed on the right. I use Jquery live preview.
 But it seems like my design can only load itself after writing and loading again the page. Any idea of how to allow the design to be generated directly ?
 [Here is my page so far](http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/writer/) (to see the effect : write something and load the page again)
check this [fiddle here (Updated by Pugazh)](https://jsfiddle.net/z0u6gtbL/2/)
[image: This is what the design look like]
Here is my javascript

```
            $(function() {
                $('textarea.source').livePreview({
                    previewElement: $('p#demo'),
                    allowedTags: ['p', 'strong', 'br', 'em', 'strike'],
                    interval: 20
                });
            });



window.onload = function wordsinblocks(self) {
    var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
        initialText = demo.textContent,
        wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word){
          return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
        });

    demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
    self.disabled = true;
    fitWords();
    window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}

function fitWords(){
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
      width = demo.offsetWidth,
      sizes = [7.69230769230769,23.07692307692307,46.15384615384614, 100],
      calculated = sizes.map(function(size){return width*size/100}),
      node, 
      i, 
      nodeWidth,
      match,
      index;


    for (i=0;i<demo.childNodes.length;i++){
      node = demo.childNodes[i];
      node.classList.remove('size-1','size-2','size-3','size-4');

      nodeWidth = node.clientWidth;
      match = calculated.filter(function(grid){
        return grid >= nodeWidth;
      })[0];
      index = calculated.indexOf(match);


      node.classList.add( 'size-' + (index+1));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "But it seems like my design can only load itself after writing and loading again the page."? On my chrome, you design will be instantly loaded. See: http://prntscr.com/b7cvye

Comment: Cause this is supposed to look like this : http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/go.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run the `wordsinblocks()` function only on `window.pageload`, but you have to run them when you update the text. Just separate the function and call it on the `reloadPreview`.

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.livePreview = function(options) {
            // [...]
            textarea.reloadPreview = function() {
                // [...]
                wordsinblocks(self);
            };
            // [...]
        });
    };

   // [...]

})(jQuery);

function wordsinblocks(self) {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
      initialText = demo.textContent,
      wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word) {
        return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
      });

  demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
  self.disabled = true;
  fitWords();
  window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}

// [...]
window.onload = wordsinblocks(self);
// [...]
```

Working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/z0u6gtbL/3/

Comment: Ok got it, any idea of how could I do that ?

Comment: Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/z0u6gtbL/2/).

I beleive `http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/writer/src/jquery.livepreview.js` is a cross reference.

You can add the `jquery.livepreview.js` directly like below to your `js` or use a local/CDN reference.

```js
/*
 * LivePreview jQuery Plugin v1.0
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Phil Haack, http://haacked.com/
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */

(function($) {
  $.fn.livePreview = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.livePreview.defaults, options);
    var previewMaxIndex = opts.previewElement.length - 1;

    var allowedTagsRegExp = new RegExp("&lt;(/?(" + opts.allowedTags.join("|") + ")(\\s+.*?)?)&gt;", "g");

    return this.each(function(i) {
      var textarea = $(this);
      var preview = $(opts.previewElement[Math.min(i, previewMaxIndex)]);

      textarea.handleKeyUp = function() {
        textarea.unbind('keyup', textarea.handleKeyUp);
        if (!preview.updatingPreview) {
          preview.updatingPreview = true;
          window.setTimeout(function() {
            textarea.reloadPreview()
          }, opts.interval);
        }
        return false;
      };

      textarea.htmlUnencode = function(s) {
        return s.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
      };

      textarea.reloadPreview = function() {
        var previewString = this.val();
        if (previewString.length > 0) {
          previewString = this.htmlUnencode(previewString);
          previewString = previewString.replace(opts.paraRegExp, "<p>$1</p><p>$2</p>");
          previewString = previewString.replace(opts.lineBreakRegExp, "$1<br />$2");
          previewString = previewString.replace(allowedTagsRegExp, "<$1>");
        }

        try {
          // Workaround for a bug in jquery 1.3.2 which is fixed in 1.4
          preview[0].innerHTML = previewString;
        } catch (e) {
          alert("Sorry, but inserting a block element within is not allowed here.");
        }

        preview.updatingPreview = false;
        this.bind('keyup', this.handleKeyUp);
      };

      textarea.reloadPreview();
    });

  };

  $.fn.livePreview.defaults = {
    paraRegExp: new RegExp("(.*)\n\n([^#*\n\n].*)", "g"),
    lineBreakRegExp: new RegExp("(.*)\n([^#*\n].*)", "g"),
    allowedTags: ['a', 'b', 'strong', 'blockquote', 'p', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'strike', 'super', 'sub', 'code'],
    interval: 80
  };

})(jQuery);


/*  Do you coding below this line  */



$(function() {
  $('textarea.source').livePreview({
    previewElement: $('p#demo'),
    allowedTags: ['p', 'strong', 'br', 'em', 'strike'],
    interval: 20
  });
});



window.onload = function wordsinblocks(self) {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    initialText = demo.textContent,
    wordTags = initialText.split(" ").map(function(word) {
      return '<span class="word">' + word + '</span>';
    });

  demo.innerHTML = wordTags.join('');
  self.disabled = true;
  fitWords();
  window.addEventListener('resize', fitWords);
}

function fitWords() {
  var demo = document.getElementById("demo"),
    width = demo.offsetWidth,
    sizes = [7.69230769230769, 23.07692307692307, 46.15384615384614, 100],
    calculated = sizes.map(function(size) {
      return width * size / 100
    }),
    node,
    i,
    nodeWidth,
    match,
    index;


  for (i = 0; i < demo.childNodes.length; i++) {
    node = demo.childNodes[i];
    node.classList.remove('size-1', 'size-2', 'size-3', 'size-4');

    nodeWidth = node.clientWidth;
    match = calculated.filter(function(grid) {
      return grid >= nodeWidth;
    })[0];
    index = calculated.indexOf(match);


    node.classList.add('size-' + (index + 1));
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
textarea {
  font-size: 2.9vw;
  font-family: "helvetica";
  resize: none;
  border: none;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 2.9vw;
  font-family: "helvetica";
}
h1 {
  font-family: Georgia, Times New Roman, Serif;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.alltop {
  display: table;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.9vw;
}
.agauche {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2.9vw;
}
.adroite {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  color: orange;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2.9vw;
}
.saisi {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
}
.preview {
  width: 50%;
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 2.9vw;
}
.source {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 2.9vw);
  padding-top: 2.9vw;
}
/* Code Syntax Styles */

.csharpcode,
.csharpcode pre {
  font-size: small;
  color: black;
  font-family: Consolas, "Courier New", Courier, Monospace;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.csharpcode pre {
  margin: 0;
}
.csharpcode .rem {
  color: #008000;
}
.csharpcode .kwrd {
  color: #00f;
}
.csharpcode .str {
  color: #006080;
}
.csharpcode .op {
  color: #0000c0;
}
.csharpcode .preproc {
  color: #c63;
}
.csharpcode .asp {
  background-color: #ff0;
}
.csharpcode .html {
  color: #800000;
}
.csharpcode .attr {
  color: #f00;
}
.csharpcode .alt {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.csharpcode .lnum {
  color: #606060;
}
#demo {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0 0 1px;
  overflow: auto;
}
#demo .word {
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  font-size: 2.9vw;
  height: 10%;
  font-family: "helvetica";
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#demo .word:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
#demo .size-1 {
  width: 7.69230769230769%;
}
#demo .size-2 {
  width: 23.07692307692307%;
}
#demo .size-3 {
  width: 46.15384615384614%;
}
#demo .size-4 {
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="http://www.o-y-o.fr/simon/writer/src/jquery.livepreview.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<div class="alltop">
  <div class="agauche">

    <p style="padding-left:5px;">Write</p>
  </div>
  <div class="adroite">
    <p style="padding-left:5px;">See</p>
  </div>
</div>





<div id="main">

  <div class="saisi">
    <textarea class="source"></textarea>
  </div>


  <div class="preview">
    <p id="demo"></p>
  </div>

</div>
```